# Unexpected Margin in Webkit Browsers

Tags: html, css, margin, fluid-layout, multiple-columns

I'm having an issue with a 2-column, fluid layout.  Both columns are inside of a div (`.dp_stage_sizer`) with `overflow: auto`; `.spl_aside` is floated to the left, `spl_main` is just plain-old `position: relative` with a `margin-left`.

This works fine so long as I use pixel values for width and margin, but as this site is to be fluid (below a certain window width, anyway) everything except the width of `.dp_stage_sizer` is in percents.  This causes `spl_main` to sprout an extra margin on its right side, so that it doesn't line up with its parent element, but *only* in Webkit browsers (although the margin is MUCH larger in Safari than Chrome).

Below is the code in as distilled a version as I could manage:

HTML:

```
<div class="dp_stage_sizer">
    <div class = "spl_aside">
        aside
    </div>
    <div class = "spl_main">
        main
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.dp_stage_sizer
{
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    overflow: auto;

    background-color: silver;
}

.spl_main
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0% 0% 0% 30%;
    overflow: hidden;

    background-color: green;
    height: 400px;
}

.spl_aside
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    overflow: hidden;

    background-color: red;
    height: 300px;
}
```

And finally a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PacmanBits/AZFVU/1/) for anyone who wants to experiment.

---

Below are images taken using Chrome's web inspector, showing the margins of each of the three divs:

`dp_stage_sizer`:
[image: margins for <code>dp_stage_sizer</code>]

`spl_aside`:
[image: margins for <code>spl_aside</code>]

`spl_main`:
[image: margins for <code>spl_main</code>]

Comment: I have no idea what this means, but I just tried switching the aside column to the right side (floated it right, and adjusted the margins on `spl_main`).  The issue does not occur in this case (there is no unexplained left-sided margin on `spl_main`)

Comment: Sounds like this could be a white-space problem. Try setting set the container 'font-size:' to  '0' and reset it for its children.

Comment: No dice =( Also, using web inspectors you can see the margin highlighted as a margin.  I'll post an image in a sec.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the web inspector reports 0 margin on the right, and that the width of `spl_aside` seems to have some affect on the magical margin.

Comment: Two things that works for me:
1. If I set .spl_main to 76% width, it fits. (though it does not make sense - 30% + 76% is not 100% where I come from) 
2. If I set .spl_aside to use position:absolute instead of float, the margins are correct.

Comment: I noticed that it offset by about 75% but I wasn't totally satisfied to make that sort of alteration without understanding why, first.  `position: absolute` works, I guess.  So long as I keep that `overflow: auto` on the top `div`.  I'll run some testing on it, right now.

Comment: Seems to work like a charm.  This is probably a more solid way to structure things, anyway.  Thanks!  Write that up as an answer so I can accept it for you!

Comment: GUH! WAAAAAAAIT.  Nope, no go.  Using `position: absolute` does not cause `dp_stage_sizer` to resize if `spl_aside` is larger (this is actually a possibility in my layout).  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate solution could be to use `inline-blocks`. How you implement this does depend on what browser support you need though. Leaving my [suggestion in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helmers/EZVUY/1/).

Comment: I'm still a little uneasy about using inline-block on a major client.  Having to rely on the *IE hack leaves me feeling like I haven't done a good enough job.  Still, it's the best answer, yet.  I'll put it into testing (this project just got put on hold until Monday).  Don't suppose you have any idea what's causing all of this?

Comment: I'm afraid not, but it feels like it should have a simple answer. Hopefully the hive-mind of Stack Overflow will solve it!

Answer (score 1):

You can work around this issue by setting `position: absolute` on `.spl_aside` instead of floating it. Be aware that this means that you lose the ability to use `clear:float` should you wish to place content below it at some point.

Comment: Sorry, I just found a flaw with this one, it was so close.  In my layout either column may be larger.  If the aside is larger it won't resize `dp_stage_sizer`.

Comment: Still +1 for the almost-answer, though